# I want to write a validation rule for the following:

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule

**restrict to select "Device Returned (Device_Returned__c)" picklist values ("Yes", "Yes - Damaged"), When Stage (StageName) IS NOT ("Closed Won", "Closed Lost")**

This is what I tried but it doesn't work as expected:

```
IF($User.Profile_Name__c = 'BAT Field Force - PT' || $User.Profile_Name__c = 'System Administrator' || $User.Profile_Name__c = 'BAT Glo Coach - PT' || $User.Profile_Name__c = 'BAT POS Agent - PT' || 
$User.Profile_Name__c = 'BAT POS Shop - PT'
&& (ISNEW()||ISCHANGED(Device_Returned__c) && 
(ISPICKVAL(Device_Returned__c,'Yes')|| ISPICKVAL(Device_Returned__c,'Yes 
- Damaged'))
&& (NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Closed Lost')||ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Closed 
Won')))),true,false)
```

Comment: So what have you tried? Where are you stuck? [edit] your question to include those details. If you're new to validation rules (or any other part of Salesforce) then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource to get you started.

Comment: Hi I have added my validation rule. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's certainly a mess you have there.

The first thing you'll want to do is to break things onto separate lines to make it easier to mentally parse and see if there are any obvious mistakes. Basically, indent like you would if it were code.

Doing that, we get

```
IF(
    $User.Profile_Name__c = 'BAT Field Force - PT' 
    || $User.Profile_Name__c = 'System Administrator' 
    || $User.Profile_Name__c = 'BAT Glo Coach - PT' 
    || $User.Profile_Name__c = 'BAT POS Agent - PT' 
    || $User.Profile_Name__c = 'BAT POS Shop - PT'
    && (
        ISNEW() 
        || ISCHANGED(Device_Returned__c) 
        && (
            ISPICKVAL(Device_Returned__c,'Yes') 
            || ISPICKVAL(Device_Returned__c,'Yes - Damaged')
        )
        && (
            NOT(
                ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Closed Lost')
                || ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Closed Won')
            )
        )
    ),
    true,
    false
)
```

Salesforce doesn't publish any documentation telling us what the precedence of `&&` and `||` are in formulas, but in Apex (and in programming languages in general) the `&&` operator takes precedence over the `||` operator.

So while you probably *think* that your Device_Returned__c/StageName check is doing

- ISNEW or ISCHANGED?
- and Device_Returned__c value 1 or value 2?
- and StageName value 1 or value2?

What is probably actually happening is

- ISCHANGED and (Device_Returned__c value 1 or value 2) and ( StageName value 1 or value2)
- or ISNEW

Likewise, I suspect that overall result is getting AND-ed with `$User.Profile_Name__c = 'BAT POS Shop - PT'` instead of that check being  part of the other profile name checks.

You can use `&&` and `||` in formulas, and you could fix this with some extra functions and parenthesis, but I think it's easier and less error-prone to use `AND()` and `OR()` in formulas instead.

Rewriting your formula to use those...

```
AND(
    OR(
        $User.Profile_Name__c = 'System Administrator',
        $User.Profile_Name__c = 'BAT Field Force - PT',
        $User.Profile_Name__c = 'BAT Glo Coach - PT',
        $User.Profile_Name__c = 'BAT POS Agent - PT',
        $User.Profile_Name__c = 'BAT POS Shop - PT'
    ),
    OR(
        ISNEW(),
        ISCHANGED(Device_Returned__c)
    ),
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Device_Returned__c', 'Yes'),
        ISPICKVAL(Device_Returned__c', 'Yes - Damaged')
    ),
    NOT(
        OR(
            ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Lost'),
            ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Won')
        )
    )
)
```

Note that the outer `IF()` has been removed because `IF(<condition>, true, false)` can always be reduced to simply `<condition>`.

From there, you need to realize that validation rules tell you when data is *invalid*, not when it is valid. The rewritten formula says, in plain language

> If the user is one of these profiles
> and the record is new or `Device_Returned__c` is changing
> and StageName isn't Closed Lost/Won
> then complain if `Device_Returned__c` is either 'Yes' or 'Yes - Damaged'

Which is the opposite of what you say you want.

Profile check and new/changing field check aside, what you want here is to check:

- Is the StageName something other than Closed Lost/Closed Won (which you're already doing. `!(x OR y)` == `!x AND !y` )
- If that's true, is `Device_Returned__c` not one of the two allowed values?

So you should enclose the entire check for `Device_Returned__c` (including the `OR()`) inside of a `NOT()`.

Comment: and if it weren't for you checking profiles, I'd say that you should just make your life easier and make this into a dependent picklist. Alas, checking profiles precludes that approach unless you want to juggle multiple record types and page layouts (which would be even _more_ work than what you have now).

Answer (score 0):

`NOT(( ISPICKVAL( Device_Returned__c , "Yes") || ISPICKVAL(Device_Returned__c , "Yes - Damaged") )) && IsClosed`

Comment: This does not work! :(

Comment: I tested it in my own Org first and it worked as expected.  Can you elaborate on why it didn't work?